# Excel macro, add date by button in next row

Tags: vba, excel

I got problem with adding date button in excel document. I wanted to speed up adding date in document just by clicking the button attached to first row. It works almost fine, adding extra cell with date in next row. But when the hour change, all earlier entries change as well. How should I modify it?

```
    Sub Makro1()
'
' Makro1 Makro
'

'
    Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=NOW()"


End Sub
```

Comment: You added function `Now()`, which shows current date. So every time you update your worksheet it will change. snagman showed you code to insert current date as value, so it will stay the same even if hour, day or any part of date will change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want every dates not to change (you just want to keep the `NOW()` value of when you have called the macro), you could just set the value of the current date to the cell value:

```
Sub Makro1()

    Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = NOW()

End Sub
```

And no need for `Select`, you can access the value directly.
Actually, if you set `Now()` as a cell formula, the value *is supposed to* change when a macro (containing the function) worksheet is called or the sheet is recalculated:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/now-function-HP010062293.aspx

Hoping that's what you want